# How to override LinkingObjects in Realm 1.0

Tags: inheritance, realm, realm-migration

I want to migrate to from Realm 0.98 to 1.0.2 but I struggle with `LinkingObjects` used in inheritance. I can not override the `linkingObjects` property as before.

Simplified my model exists of a `Person` that has `pets` and `cats`. `Cat` is a subclass of `Pet` (as it shared properties which I omitted here). It is important to be handle cats in a separate list in the persons. Lets just assume it's an awesome cats app that also has some support for other pets.

In 0.98 is looks like this:

```swift
class Person: Object {
    let pets = List<Pet>()
    let cats = List<Cat>()
}

class Pet: Object {
    var linkedOwner: Person? {
        get {
            return linkingObjects(Pet.self, forProperty: "pets").first
        }
    }
}

class Cat: Pet {
    override var linkedOwner: Person? {
        get {
            return linkingObjects(Cat.self, forProperty: "cats").first
        }
    }
}
```

I since `linkingObjects` is used in the getter I can easily override it to change the property from `"pets"` to `"cats"`.

Now since 1.0 using `LinkingObjects` instead `linkingObjects` it is different, [for example as described here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3525#issuecomment-216920757):

```swift
class Person: Object {
    let pets = List<Pet>()
    let cats = List<Cat>()
}

class Pet: Object {
    let linkedOwners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "pets")
    var linkedOwner: Person? {
        get {
            return linkedOwners.first
        }
    }
}

class Cat: Pet {
    // this does not compile: Cannot override with a stored property 'linkedOwners'
    override let linkedOwners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "cats") 

    // linkedOwner would be the same so we don't need to override anymore 
}
```

**How can I change / override the property used for the `LinkingObjects` in the `Cat` class?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @bdash mentioned it's not feasible the old way. Hence I ended up creating a new base class that provides an abstract property to be overriding with a forwarding to the actual specific `LinkingObjects` property.

```
class Person: Object {
    let pets = List<Pet>()
    let cats = List<Cat>()
}

class Animal: Object {
   var linkedOwner : Person? { fatalError("override me!") }
}

class Pet: Animal {
    private let linkedOwners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "pets")
    override var linkedOwner: Person? { return linkedOwners.first }
}

class Cat: Animal {
    private let linkedOwners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "cats") 
    override var linkedOwner: Person? { return linkedOwners.first }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I change / override the property used for the `LinkingObjects` in the `Cat` class?

The short answer is, you can't change the property used for a `LinkingObjects`. If you want a subclass to expose `LinkingObjects` from a different property, you'll need to declare a *new* property of type `LinkingObjects`, and use that instead.